# how can i write a transform pass input 2 modules?

Tags: llvm

i want cut sth. from module1 and put into module2 like this
ex:
i try modify run mothod in passmanager.h and passmanagerinternel.h but when i compile,it didnt work

```
reservedAnalyses XXXPass::run(Module& module,Module& module2, ModuleAnalysisManager &MAM) 
 PreservedAnalyses FuncInputPass::run(Module& module, Module& module2,ModuleAnalysisManager &MAM) {  
        SMDiagnostic Err;
        LLVMContext Context;
        std::string InputFuncName;
        errs()<<"input func name:";
        //std::cin>>InputFuncName;
        for(Function &Func : module2){ 
          errs()<<"1"<<"\n";
          if("inner2"==Func.getName()&&!module.getFunction("inner2")){
            std::ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open(module.getName().str(), std::ios::app);
            std::string IRString;
            raw_string_ostream os(IRString);
            Func.print(os, nullptr);
            ofs<<IRString;
            os.flush();
            ofs.close();
          }
        }
        
      std::unique_ptr<Module> OrigMod(parseIRFile(module.getName().str(), Err, Context));
      Module &OriM = dynamic_cast<Module&>(*OrigMod);
      Function *ffunc=OriM.getFunction("inner2");
      for(Function &F : OriM){  
        if(F.getName()!="inner2"){  
          for (BasicBlock &BB : F){
            for (Instruction &inst : BB){
              if(isa<StoreInst>(inst)){
                errs()<<"get store inst"<<"\n";
                CallInst *mycallinst;
                mycallinst = CallInst::Create(ffunc);
                mycallinst->insertAfter(&inst);
              }
            }
          }
        }
```